# Get Rectangle Coordinates drawn in Pane

Tags: javafx, rectangles

How do I get the coordinates of a drawn rectangle in a pane?

This is how I draw the rectangle:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.setX(50);
r.setY(50);
r.setWidth(200);
r.setHeight(100);
r.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
r.setStrokeWidth(1);
r.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
DragResizeMod.makeResizable(r);
pane.getChildren().add(r);
```

this is the link of the class im using to resize the rectangle

https://github.com/varren/JavaFX-Resizable-Draggable-Node/blob/master/src/sample/DragResizeMod.java

So how do I get the coordinates of a drawn rectangle? Without passing the coordinates to a list before drawing it.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please describe more detailed what you're trying to achieve? [1] Do you want the coordinates of an arbitrary rectangle __being drawn__? [2] Do you want the coordinates of a rectangle __before it will be drawn__?

Comment: i draw the rectangle using the mouse press and drag. and i also use this code https://github.com/varren/JavaFX-Resizable-Draggable-Node/blob/master/src/sample/DragResizeMod.java
to resize the rectangle. so if i resize the rectangle it changes its coordinates. so what i really need is to get its coordinates after its resized

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions, but an easy one could be to add a handler to the `xProperty` [xProperty @ Rectangle JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html#xProperty) and analogous `yProperty` like this:

```
rectangle.xProperty().addListener((Observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("X position changed from <" + oldValue + "> to <" + newValue + ">");
});
```

For completeness you should also add a handler to the `widthProperty` (and analogous the `heightProperty`), too. As the JavaDoc cites for the `xProperty`:

> Defines the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle.

Meaning that if you e.g. change the size but the upper left corner is still in the same position, you won't get notified for the `xProperty`!

Comment: where do i suppose to add the code? i add it in the "initialize" but nothing happens

Comment: You could add it where you're creating the rectangle. E.g. right behind `Rectangle r = new Rectangle();` Set a breakpoint to the `System.out.prinln()` in the handler from my code and check if it gets called.

Comment: thats what i did. but it doesn't call the code. i change the rectangle.xProperty to r.xProperty because r is my variable name

Comment: its working now. how do i create an event listener to each rectangle drawn?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the coordinates after resizing: use the `boundsInParent` property. Unless you apply transforms with a shear/rotate component, this will give you the bounds of the `Rectangle`. If you use a `Parent` that adjusts the position of it's children, the position may not be correct, but `Pane` is not one of them (but many of it's subclasses are):

```
Rectangle r = ...
...
// resize

Bounds boundsAfterResize = r.getBoundsInParent();
```

Comment: how do i use this code? after resizing the rectangle i get "0"

Comment: @pdftoimage a) you cannot get 0, since `Bounds` is not primitive and b) If a certain property of those bounds is `0`, it's because you modified the `Rectangle` be resized/relocated/transformed in a way that makes this property `0`. If this is not the desired value for that property, you need to find the bug in ***your code*** (You aren't showing anything of the resizing in your question BTW).